# What's a good HTML naming convention for model binding complex nested types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, viewmodel, model-binding

If I have an object that is composed of nested complex types, e.g. a ViewModel that has a `List<Fu>` and a `List<Bar>`

```
public class WarViewModel
{
    List<Fu> Fu { get; set; }
    List<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Fu
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Soldier Private { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id {get;set;}        
    public Soldier Private { get; set; }
}

public class Soldier
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

if I had a `form` that contained 2 `select` lists, either with Fu or Bar, where each `option` represented each soldier in the list, and the option had attributes containing Id, Name and Age, such as

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<WarViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("WarAction", "War")) { %>        
    <% foreach (var soldier in Fu) %>
        <select class="fu">
            <option id='<%= soldier.Id %>' age='<%= soldier.Age %>'><%= soldier.Name %></option>
        </select>
    <% } %>

    <% foreach (var soldier in Bar) %>
        <select class="bar">
            <option id='<%= soldier.Id %>' age='<%= soldier.Age %>'><%= soldier.Name %></option>
        </select>
    <% } %>        
<% } %>
```

What naming convention do I need to use so that when the form is submitted, the following action method's WarViewModel will be populated with the soldiers that are selected in both lists?

```
public ActionResult WarAction(WarViewModel war)
{
    return View();
}
```

My understanding now is that the model binder won't know soldier is which, so it won't know which Id is associated with which soldier. Is there a way for me to work around this? I know that the code above won't validate but I'm trying to implement a proof of concept for myself.

Also, what needs to be changed to make this approach RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your trying to do is already supported:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx